# Read memory safely on Windows

Tags: windows, winapi, memory

On Linux and other Unix-like systems, I can safely read portions of both the current and other processes' address space, by reading at the desired offset in `/proc/PID/mem`. If the address is unmapped, instead of a segfault I simply get errno `EIO`.

Is there a way to do a similar thing on Windows, both for the current process and for arbitrary processes on the system?

Comment: [`ReadProcessMemory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-readprocessmemory)

Comment: What does *"safe"* mean to you?